# How to change sold_individually product property in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, metadata, product

I need to update '_sold_individually' field of product in woocommerce.

I have using below field it isn't working

```
update_post_meta($product->get_id(), '_sold_individually', "yes");
```

Any alternate please help thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are already using the `WC_Product` instance object `$product`, you can better try using `set_sold_individually()` dedicated method this way:

```
$product->set_sold_individually( true );
$product->save();
```

It should better work and sync product cached data…